# This app works in single activities but crahes when added to app drawer

Tags: android, kotlin

So i tried this using kotlin,though it runs in java android. 
it works in java as a single activity though when added to the app drawer 
it crashes when selected, when converted to kotlin code it crashes the app when opened. 
Any help that would make this work is greatly appreciated

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Stackoverflow, to better understand your question, we need a more detailed explanation about what you were doing, your expected result and if it's possible some piece of code.

Comment: 1.) crash stack trace 2.) relevant code

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1t-2IgL9BQqaw7v51StEgkrOT4c7KHPFnAM88H5t1BiI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: sorry the code was really long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crash is appearing because your `ShareFragment` inherits from `AppCompatActivity` instead of `Fragment`